# host unable to connect to network or internet, when eth0 is under bridge

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, virtual-network

I am actually trying to use this [docker-net-dhcp](https://github.com/devplayer0/docker-net-dhcp)
open source network driver for docker, to enable
containers get ip addresses from DHCP of the host-network.

The steps are,

```
ip link add my-bridge type bridge
ip link set my-bridge up
ip link set eth0 master my-bridge               ---------(1)
...
```

Here, after this, i am no longer able to connect to the network from the host.

Again, when i create the docker network using that plugin,

Containers are able to succesfully get ip addresses from DHCP, connect to the internet,
and thus to

any computer in the host network but not the host.

Even a ping between a container and host is saying unreachable.

I am not understanding why host is having this issue,

am i missing something?

This is what I THINK should be scenario when i run above commands (1),

( I KNOW I MIGHT BE TOTAL WRONG HERE, SO CORRECT ME UP IF I AM TOTALLY WRONG ABOUT
UNDERSTANDING THIS)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When 'eth0' becomes a bridge port, it is completely taken over by the virtual switch and becomes disconnected from the host's TCP/IP stack. All IP handling for the host OS is moved to the new 'my-bridge' interface, which – in addition to representing the bridge – also connects to the so-called "host port" of the bridge (missing from your diagram).

[image]

So you need to move all IP configuration from 'eth0' to 'my-bridge' for networking on the host to continue working. (As you can see in the docker-net-dhcp README, the author demonstrates running the 'dhcpcd' DHCP client on the 'my-bridge' interface.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply!
and thanks lot for this nice explanation!

Comment: Thank you for clarying my long-time doubt! Also thanks for this image edit!